# Using Expression in Python to see which one doesn't belong

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following regular expression:

`c[aeiou]+[a-z]*t`

Which of the following words does NOT belong *in full* to the language defined by this expression?

1) clout

2) caught

3) coat

4) coot

5) coat

How do i Solve this? (It's in python)

Comment: https://regex101.com/ according to the regex the second character is a vowel. Only one of your 5 words don't have a vowel in its second place.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense now! :)

Answer (score 0):

- '[]' selects 'one of' members in the bracket
- '+' means the selection from [] can occur one or more times
- '-' signifies range : from a to z
- '*' means the selection from the second [] can occur zero or more times

The answer would be 'c' 'one or more vowels' 'zero or more alphabets' 't'

See which answer fits the pattern

https://cheatography.com/davechild/cheat-sheets/regular-expressions/

Regex is not python specific